# Won't connect to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm confused...I'm using the same code in a different document and in there it's not a problem to get a connection to the database.

But in the new document it's just not working...(password, username, database name...all is checked and correct) :-/

```
<?php

define ("DB_HOST", "db1234567.db.hello.com"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "db1234567"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","password123"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","db1234567"); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

?>
```

In the browser I get this: "Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'db1234567'@'123.123.12.12 (using password: YES) in /homepages/12/1234567/test/test.php on line 8
Couldn't make connection."

Would be cool if someone could help me :) I'm not seeing any error...

Thx!

Comment: Are those documents in same server (behind same IP)?

Comment: What privliges does the user have ?

Comment: check user, password and host settings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do. 'Access Denied' is a pretty clear error. Either the credentials are incorrect or the user is blocked. MySQL is responding though, so the problem is in the username/password.

Comment: Hmm..ok! I'll check again...but used copy&paste, so the values should be right :-/
@Alvar FinSoft Soome ...yes all in same server

Comment: ...pretty stupid mistake! copy&paste error! found it now :) Thanks for your help!!!